# What do you call the load time binding of DLL that is done at startup without stopping if DLL doesn't exist

Tags: winapi

What do you call this type of dynamic link binding?  I know there is a name for it, I just can't recall what it is to look up more technical details about it and search engines aren't helping.

```
// technique to support functions that may not exist in other windows versions.
typedef void (WINAPI *LPFN_GetSystemInfo) (LPSYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);
LPFN_GetSystemInfo fnGetSystemInfo=(LPFN_GetSystemInfo) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), "GetSystemInfo");
```

Comment: Microsoft calls it [run-time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-run-time-dynamic-linking).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual Studio. It's a WinAPI question.

Comment: It was a feature of visual c++ if I recall, it's not like the run-time dynamic linking shown that uses loadlibrary, this version you don't have that, you have exactly what I put above.  It used to be documented but I can't find it.

Comment: You are probably thinking of [delay-loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls), a variation of run-time dynamic linking that lets you customize module and import lookup. Though it is set up much like load-time dynamic linking, imports are looked up strictly at run-time.